# In MySQL, how do I join and only get the first of a set

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: events, products and a association table event_products.

events:event_id,

products: product_id, product_name

event_products:event_id, product_id

There can be none or many products associated with an event.

My question is I need a list of events, and only one resulting row for each event. In the list I need only one product for each event, preferably the first one added,  or if that can't be done, the one with lowest product_id.

```
select e.event_id, ep.product_id, p.product_name
FROM `events` e
LEFT OUTER JOIN event_products ep on ep.event_id = e.event_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN products p on p.product_id = ep.product_id;
```

will, ofcourse, return multiple rows for every event that have multiple products assigned.

thanks

Comment: The event_id is the primary keyfor events, as is the product-id for products. the combination event_id and product_id is the primary key for event_products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select e.event_id, min(ep.product_id), p.product_name
FROM `events` e
LEFT OUTER JOIN event_products ep on ep.event_id = e.event_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN products p on p.product_id = ep.product_id
group by e.event_id, p.product_name
;
```

Comment: Thank, this works with one minor change. We just need group by e.event_id and we should not include p.product_name. so the SQL for Mysql is: select e.event_id, min(ep.product_id), p.product_name
FROM `events` e
LEFT OUTER JOIN event_products ep on ep.event_id = e.event_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN products p on p.product_id = ep.product_id
group by e.event_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.event_id, p.product_id, p.product_name 
FROM products p, 
(SELECT e.event_id as event_id, min(p.product_id) as product_id
FROM events e, event_products ep, products p
where e.event_id = ep.event_id, ep.product_id = p.product_id
group_by e.event_id) e
```

Give this a try.

Comment: hmm, thanks. I can't start with the product table since I need the events that have no products also. Also mysql says your sql has a syntax error that I can't find.

Comment: try the inner query and see if it gives you your desired output, without the product_name. I apologize for the syntax error as I don't have a mysql command line to try out.

Comment: Mysql returns: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.product_id group_by e.event_id) e' at line 5

Comment: this may be a clue. this works without the product_name. the subselect doesn't let me select more than one value....    select e.event_id, 
(select min(ep.product_id)
FROM event_products ep 
WHERE ep.event_id = e.event_id
) as product
FROM `events` e

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `ep`.`product_id`, `p`.`product_name`
FROM `event_products` AS `ep`
JOIN `products` AS `p` USING (`product_id`)
GROUP BY `ep`.`event_id` HAVING `ep`.`product_id`=MIN(`ep`.`product_id`)
```

Make sure to use proper indexes for this query (test with EXPLAIN)

By your comment I guess that you'll need additional INDEX(`product_id`) on table event_products.

Comment: A problem with this solution is that it will not return events without product. The SELECT has to be `events` centric. @randy's solution with a minor tweek works. THANKS EVERYONE!!!

Comment: "it will not return events without product" that wasn't a requirement =S Your welcome :)